# How can I protect my savings against inflation? [UK]

Tags: united-kingdom, inflation

How can I ensure that my savings keep up with inflation, even after any tax due is taken off the returns?

Answer (score 11):

If your primary concern is inflation, you can buy an [Inflation-index bond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation-indexed_bond).  This is a widely available bond that many countries offer.  In the UK, this is referred to as the "[Inflation-linked Gilt](http://www.dmo.gov.uk/index.aspx?page=Gilts/Indexlinked)", issued by the [UK Debt Management Office](http://www.dmo.gov.uk/).  These bonds will value the investment in relation to a certain inflation index. In the case of the Inflation-linked Gilt, they use the [Retail Prices Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retail_Price_Index_%28United_Kingdom%29).

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, you could use an index fund or ETF that invests in instruments indexed to the [Consumer Price Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Price_Index_%28United_Kingdom%29). One option is the [iShares Barclays £ Index-Linked Gilts (INXG)](http://uk.ishares.com/en/rc/products/INXG), which

> is an exchange traded fund (ETF) that aims to track the performance of the Barclays World Government Inflation-Linked Bond Index as closely as possible.

You still need to take into account commissions, among other factors, and understand that any investment comes with risk. Note that this ETF *aims* to track the performance of an inflation-linked bond index. It may not succeed all the time. **This isn't a fool-proof strategy, unfortunately, because investing is always a trade-off between risk and return.** By excepting a higher return, i.e., one that can keep up with inflation, you do bear a higher level of risk.

[Vanguard.co.uk](https://www.vanguard.co.uk/documents/adv/literature/inflation-linked-bonds.pdf) has good general information about inflation-indexed instruments and funds too.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to buy whatever you use inside one of the tax-free savings vehicle (ie, some sort of ISA or similar), especially if you're a high rate tax payer. If you don't, the 40% tax on it will pretty much make it impossible to get a return anywhere near the rate of inflation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the money immediately I suggest some of the large equity income Investment trusts would be a good way of beating inflation Lowland and City of London are two that come to mind.