# What can I do to protect my savings from inflation in my national currency (Mexico)?

Tags: savings, inflation, mexico

What can I do to protect my savings from inflation?  I'm in Mexico.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but I found that this question is an exact duplicate, unfortunately :(

Comment: @overmann Please provide a link to the duplicate.  If the difference in wording is useful, we may keep this question around with a link to the other one.

Comment: Yes, better. I'll re-open.  BTW, I think the Mexico angle makes this question distinct from other similar ones.

Comment: the answer of user5316 is basically the same selected answer from this question, that is phrased exactly as mine: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/how-can-i-protect-my-savings-against-inflation-uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by saying that the bulk of your savings shouldn't be in cash. If you haven't done so already, open an investment account (I'm not sure what kind of tax-advantaged accounts there are in Mexico, but you should look into it). If you buy a mix of stocks and bonds with American and international coverage -- which is as easy as buying a handful of index funds -- then you're protected from inflation in Mexico.